How to make qt scrollbar remain full sized after mouse leaves
I'm using a QScrollBar widget.  When my mouse is over the widget, it becomes full sized.  When I move my mouse away, it is nearly hidden.  I want the widget to remain full sized all the time.  Doing my nut trying to figure this out without re-writing the style sheets.

Those are called "transient scrollbars", and their behavior depends on the OS and style used in Qt; they're automatically used on macOS (based on the user configuration). You may try to create a custom QProxyStyle, overriding styleHint() and always return 0 for QStyle::SH_ScrollBar_Transient. Alternatively, use setStyle() on the scroll bar with QStyleFactory::create('fusion'), or use a custom style sheet.

musicamante's answer works.  Be sure to add the QStyleFactory from QT.  I eneded up using a slider instead.  But for another reason.
